# Heroku pipeline promotion not updating github

Tags: github, heroku

I have a project in Github with 2 branches, [master] and [production].
I linked them with Heroku's pipeline and made it deploy automatically from [master] (but not for [production]) . So whenever my team pushes code into the master branch, the project hosted on Heroku is automatically updated and we can see the changes in the web application. Also, there is now a [Promote to production...] button available.

When I clicked this button, the [production] web application was updated with no issues, but the codes in github under the [production] branch was still the old one.

Earlier, I had changed one config file in the production branch manually (to match the production environment) so it now says [This branch is 1 commit ahead, xx commits behind master.] Maybe I have to resolve this first before I promote to production?? Can I do this in the Github UI in the browser?

Comment: I deleted and recreated the branch, and relinked it with the Heroku pipeline so it's fine now, but I don't think this is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Heroku integrates with GitHub to make it easy to deploy code living on GitHub to apps running on Heroku. When GitHub integration is configured for a Heroku app, Heroku can automatically build and release (if the build is successful) pushes to the specified GitHub repo.

You're seeing the correct behaviour. Heroku's [GitHub Integration](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration) lets you automate Heroku deploys based on pushes to your GitHub repository. It isn't supposed to go the other way.

This is a good thing. What would you expect to happen in the case of a merge conflict?

Comment: so what is the "proper" way of doing this?

Comment: @sikidhart, you haven't sufficiently explained what "this" is. We need to know the actual problem you're trying to solve, not the solution you think you need. (I.e., _why_ do you want GitHub to be updated when you promote a pipeline? What benefit does it give?) Please read about the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Ok maybe I don't fully understand what's going on.. In Git, I have [Master] and [Production], and in Heroku I also have [Master] and [Production]. We code, commit, push to [Master(git)], then [Master(heroku)] is also updated automatically. By "this" I meant "what is the proper way of updating [Production]? My original assumption was the [Promote to production] button. Since the [Production(git)] is not updated this way, I instead recreated the [Production(git)] from master and re-linked it with Heroku and manually deployed. It works, but it then makes me wonder what the [Promote] button is for

Comment: The promote button and your Git branches are entirely unrelated. Promoting using the button (or the `heroku pipelines:promote` command)  reuses the slug from the previous pipeline stage resulting in faster deployment (compared with building) and guarantees that the slugs are identical. If you want your `production` branch in your Git repository to be updated you can do that manually, e.g. using `git reset`.

Comment: OK I got it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where my project would deploy to Heroku without issue but github would not be updated. I did this and it worked for me:

```
git push --set-upstream origin main
```